# Java code goes infinite loop when trying to replace certain string

Tags: java, regex, loops

The following code replaces the occurrence of the string in between % %.

```
String OrgStr = "Alarm for %Received Number% has arrived %test% is ok. Please visit %Received Number%";
String rcNumber = "1234567";

int firstPer, secPer;
do
{
    firstPer = OrgStr.indexOf('%'); //position of first %
    secPer = OrgStr.indexOf('%', firstPer+1); //position of second %

    //extract the string in between first % and second %
    String toBeReplac = OrgStr.substring(firstPer, secPer+1);

    //The replaced string
    //if (toBeReplac.equals("%Received Number%"))// if i put this if condition then code goes to infinite loop
        OrgStr=OrgStr.substring(0, firstPer)+ rcNumber +OrgStr.substring((secPer+1),OrgStr.length());

    firstPer = OrgStr.indexOf('%', firstPer+1);
}while(firstPer>0);

System.out.println(OrgStr);
```

As i have mentioned in the above code, when i put the line `if (toBeReplac.equals("%Received Number%"))`  the code goes in the infinite loop. I want to made the replacement only if the string in between % is Received Number.

Comment: I would imagine that the if statement fails then and you arent performing the substring, so the index position will never change

Comment: Guess what would happen when you are left with one `%` in the string.

Comment: Ever heard of `String.format`?

Comment: Use a proper REGEX to do this, its much easier

Comment: String.replace("%Received Number%", replacementString);

Comment: i cannot use replace function . so i am trying this character wise replacement

Comment: What happens when you are trying to use `replaceAll` method?

Comment: using replace or replaceall shows me error ' "Semantic Error: No applicable overload for a method with signature "replace(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)" was found in type "java.lang.String". Perhaps you wanted the overloaded version "java.lang.String replace(char $1, char $2);" instead?"'

Comment: Can we know which version of Java you are using? Can you print result of `System.getProperty("java.version")`?

Comment: i didnot get any result when i run `System.getProperty("java.version")`

Comment: @Pshemo can you please look into this issue. It would be a great help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122567/java-string-replacement-works-only-with-character-not-with-string)

Comment: I suspect that you might be using very old version of Java, maybe 1.3 or older. Normally this information is stored in system properties but since `java.version` seems not to be correct key try printing all properties and see if you will find some informations. You should be able to get them by printing result of `System.getProperties()`.

Comment: If that was the problem then consider updating your JDK to something newer like Java 7 or maybe even 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you reinitialize the value of **firstPer** on each iteration:

```
firstPer = OrgStr.indexOf('%');
```

**firstPer** always has the value of the first occurrence of '%' and that's why you have an endless loop.

So you need to add a second parameter to that call to make sure that the value of **firstPer** is updated or initialize **firstPer** somewhere else, just once, and update its value properly.

**EDIT**

To clarify, you just need to cut the sentence

```
firstPer = OrgStr.indexOf('%');
```

and paste it before **do**. You will then obtain the following output:

> Alarm for 1234567 has arrived %test% is ok. Please visit 1234567

I guess that's the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
      String Str = "Alarm for %Received Number% has arrived %test% is ok. Please visit %Received Number%";
      System.out.println(Str.replaceAll("%Received Number%","Java"));
```

OutPut :

```
         Alarm for AMROOD has arrived %test% is ok. Please visit AMROOD
```

Comment: I cannot use replace and replaceALL function.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122567/java-string-replacement-works-only-with-character-not-with-string

Answer (score 0):

Correct code would do:

```
firstPer = OrgStr.indexOf('%'); //position of first %
secPer = OrgStr.indexOf('%', firstPer+1); //position of second %
if (firstPer == -1 || secPer == 0) {
    break;
}
```

(Or invert the condition and place the rest of the loop inside the if.)

One would better use the more efficient pattern replacement with a StringBuffer

```
public String eval(String s) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern variablePattern = Pattern.compile("%([\\w ]{0,20})%");
    Matcher matcher = variablePattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String variable = matcher.group(1);
        String value = matcher.group(0);
        switch (variable) {
            case "":
                value = "%"; // "%%" becomes a single "%" (self-escaped.
                break;
            case "Received Number":
                value = "123456";
                break;
            case "test":
                value = "...";
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such variable: " + variable);
        }
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, value);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Here I considered variable names to consist only out word chars or spaces, upto maximal 20 characters. This should help with sole percents in the text. And a percent might be realized by the variable "%%".

If you maintain the variables in a map name-to-value, you would not need a switch statement,

```
public String eval(String s, Map<String, String> variables) {

}
```